Github pipeline for angular js project
I have this github pipeline I just created to automatically deploy an angular js project, that is compiled with the gulp command.
name: Node.js CI with Gulp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [6.3.0]

    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Set up Node.js
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: npm install

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: node -v

    - name: npm version
      run: npm -v

    - name: Install Gulp CLI
      run: npm install -g gulp-cli

    - name: Run Gulp
      run: gulp

    - name: List files after Gulp
      run: ls

However, when I get to the npm install -g gulp-cli i get this error:
npm ERR! Linux 6.5.0-1021-azure
npm ERR! argv "/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/6.3.0/x64/bin/node" "/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/6.3.0/x64/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "gulp-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG

npm ERR! typeerror Error: Missing required argument #1

This is my gulpfile by the way:
var gulp = require('gulp');

var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp-tasks');

gulp.task('default', ['sass', 'templatecache', 'js', 'lessCSS', 'sassCSS']);

I haven't tried anything new because I'm new to pipelines.

What's you node version and do you also have gulp as a dependency in package.json?

The node version I have to use to compile the angular js project is 6.3.0. And this is the version of gulp i have in the package.json file:
"gulp": "^3.5.6",
"gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.5.0",
"gulp-install": "^1.1.0",
"gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
"gulp-util": "^2.2.14",


Can you try with node version above 8

I think the issue is with the npm version, but I dont know how to change it in the pipeline

Try hardcoding the node version in line with: node-version: 20.

You can also add it like strategy: matrix: node-version: 20.x before the steps method and keep your current workflow as is.

will it still work? Because my angular 1 project has to run with node 6.3.0 and it's compiled using the gulp command

Thats how I've been doing it to manually deploy the frontend project

Does this answer your question? "code EMISSINGARG" error when running rpm install

The problem was that i needed to instal the gulp-cli version compatible with node version 6.3.0.
This is the pipeline that just worked for me:
# .github/workflows/docker-build.yml

name: Docker Build and Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [6.3.0]

steps:
- name: Checkout repository
  uses: actions/checkout@v2

- name: Set up Node.js
  uses: actions/setup-node@v3
  with:
    node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

- name: Install dependencies
  run: |
    node -v
    npm -v

- name: Go to dir
  run: ls

- name: Go to dir
  run: stat www/js/app.js

- name: Install Gulp CLI globally
  run: npm install

- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm install -g gulp-cli@2.2.0

- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm rebuild node-sass

- name: Run gulpfile
  run: gulp

- name: stat after build
  run: stat www/js/app.js

- name: List files after Gulp
  run: ls

